# Wpf C# DateTime Database

Tags: c#, wpf, sql-server-ce

I have two tables in my database, `energyinfo` (t1) and `enerfyinfometers` (t2).

I have a start and stop time in `t1` like 500 min difference.

I want to add the time in between `t1` (start and stop) for every one minute in `t2`.

Here's my code. it takes a lot of time to run and `t1` entries is happening but fails to do `t2`.

```
if (dbContext == null)
{
    dbContext = Context.Create("d:\\temp\\new.sdf", "");

    var start = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime time2 = DateTime.Now;

    // time = time + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
    time2 = time2 + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);

    Random rnd = new Random();
    double Counter = 50;
    var stop = start.AddMinutes(15);

    double value2 =36;

    for (int i = 1; i < 36; i++)
    {
        Counter = Counter + 0.5; 
        double value3 = rnd.Next (2,12) +0.5;
        double value4 = value3 / 2;
        double value = rnd.Next(50) +  0.5;

        value2 += (value / 60);
        double roundedValue = Math.Ceiling(value2) + 1;
        int LMH = rnd.Next(0, 3);

        dbContext.EnergyInfo.Add(new EnergyInfo() 
                                     { EId = i, 
                                       Timestamp = time, type = LMH, 
                                       startTime = start, stopTime = stop, 
                                       demandCharge = value3, 
                                       threshHold = 70, 
                                       normalCharge = value4, 
                                       peakDuration = 900 });

        dbContext.SaveChanges();

        for (var x = start; x < stop; x.AddMinutes(1))
        {
            var ob = new EnergyMeterInfo() { Timestamp = x, MeterId = 5, 
                                             powerConsumptionKW = Counter, 
                                             cumlativePwrConsumption = roundedValue, 
                                             EnergyInfoId = i };

            using (dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
            {
                dbContext.EnergyMeterInfo.Add(ob);
            }
        }

        start = stop;
        stop = start.AddMinutes(500);

        dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}

MessageBox.Show(dbContext.EnergyInfo.Count() + " Records found !" + dbContext.EnergyMeterInfo.Count() + " found");
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: @MikeEason no error!, Code keeps running for a long time with out any results in DataBase.

Comment: error in the   Loop 
 for (var x = start; x < stop; x.AddMinutes(1))

Comment: In your **for loop declaration**, you are calling `x.AddMinutes(1)`. This is effectively adding 1 minute every time the loop has completed, therefore `x` will never be greater than `stop`. Looks like you need to rethink your for loop logic.

Comment: The loop logic is ok. Just the loop variable isn't incremented.

Answer (score 2):

`x.AddMinutes(1)` does not change the value of `x`. Instead it returns a new DateTime instance, which you should then assign to `x`.

The loop should therefore look like this:

```
for (var x = start; x < stop; x = x.AddMinutes(1))
{
    ...
}
```